# Add and style content to the first objects' child

Tags: html, css

I want to select the first `<fieldset>` of the page and then give the `<legend>` within an `::after` content.

I tried it by selecting `fieldset:first-child > legend::after {`, but this doesn't give it any style at all.

I also tried it by selecting `fieldset > legend:first-child::after {` but this gives all legend's added content as it's the first child of the fieldset.

**Achieved result by my code:**

[image: Achieved result]

**Expected / wanted result**

[image: Expected / wanted result]

<kbd>[**jsFiddle DEMO that replicates the issue**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cdz81o1/)</kbd>

Any CSS-only suggestions and/or solutions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `fieldset > legend::after` to `fieldset:first-of-type > legend::after`.
`:first-item` isn't a valid selector but `:first-of-type` will do what you are after.

```css
fieldset:first-of-type > legend::after {
    content: " ADDED CONTENT";
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>This legend needs added content</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>This legend doesn't need added content</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>This legend doesn't need added content</legend>
</fieldset>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/t7uyg96e/

Answer (score 2):

[Try with the first-child](http://www.css3create.com/first-child)

```
fieldset:first-child > legend::after {
    content: " ADDED CONTENT";
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet of CSS:

```
fieldset:first-child > legend::after {
    content: " ADDED CONTENT";
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```